# How to move the focus to the tray icon

Tags: c#, system-tray

How to trigger something like win+b in a program to move the focus to the system tray

After searching I didn't find a way
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHZ46.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETFOCUS, ref nData)
```